# discard all SourceGraphic colors/alpha and recolor?

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I have a shape with a stroke. The fill is orange with 50% opacity (so alpha = .5 and rgb(255,112,0)) and the stroke is blue (no transparency).

Using filters, I've been trying to make a copy (similar to a drop shadow, but without the blur). I'd like the copy to be solid orange.

But I just can't seem to get this as `feColorMatrix` continues to use `SourceGraphic` values.

No idea why, but if my shape fill is no transparency, and I also use `feComponentTransfer` again, I can get the solid shape copy.

The shape on the right is the one I'd like to make solid orange (or any color and opacity I choose), regardless of shape/stroke fill/opacity.

```html
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="960" height="540" class="slide" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" fill-rule="evenodd">
      <rect width="960" height="540" stroke="#385D8A" fill="white" stroke-width="3" class="testSlideBorder" />

      <svg x="10" y="10" overflow="visible" stroke="#0000FF" stroke-miterlimit="8" stroke-width="4">
        <defs>
        <filter id="offsetColoredShape" height="500%" width="500%" x="-275%" y="-275%">
         <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="
                                        0 0 0 0 1 
                                        0 0 0 0 0.439
                                        0 0 0 0 0 
                                        0 0 0 1 0"
                                       result="changeToOrangeFill"/>

     <feComponentTransfer result="changedAgain">
            <feFuncR type="linear" slope="1" />
            <feFuncG type="linear" slope="0.439" />
            <feFuncB type="linear" slope="0" />
            <feFuncA type="linear" slope="1" />
</feComponentTransfer>

     <feOffset dx="120"/>
     </filter>               
  </defs>
<use xlink:href="#star" filter="url(#offsetColoredShape)" />
        <path id="star" fill="rgb(255,112,0)" fill-opacity="0.5" d="M0,63.904L17.609,51.5L8.562,31.952L30.014,30.014L31.952,8.562L51.5,17.609L63.904,0L76.309,17.609L95.857,8.562L97.795,30.014L119.247,31.952L110.199,51.5L127.809,63.904L110.199,76.309L119.247,95.857L97.795,97.795L95.857,119.247L76.309,110.199L63.904,127.809L51.5,110.199L31.952,119.247L30.014,97.795L8.562,95.857L17.609,76.309Z" />
      </svg>

    </svg>
```

Notice in the `<path/>` that `fill-opacity="0.5"`. If I change that to `fill-opacity="1"`, it works as expected. Here's what that looks like:

```html
      <svg x="10" y="10" overflow="visible" fill="#4472C4" stroke="#0000FF" stroke-miterlimit="8" stroke-width="4">
        <defs>
        <filter id="offsetColoredShape" height="500%" width="500%" x="-275%" y="-275%">
         <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="
                                        0 0 0 0 1 
                                        0 0 0 0 0.439
                                        0 0 0 0 0 
                                        0 0 0 1 0"
                                       result="changeToOrangeFill"/>

     <feComponentTransfer result="changedAgain">
            <feFuncR type="linear" slope="1" />
            <feFuncG type="linear" slope="0.439" />
            <feFuncB type="linear" slope="0" />
            <feFuncA type="linear" slope="1" />
        </feComponentTransfer>

     <feOffset dx="120"/>
     </filter>               
        </defs>
        <use xlink:href="#star" filter="url(#offsetColoredShape)" />
        <path id="star" fill="rgb(255,112,0)" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,63.904L17.609,51.5L8.562,31.952L30.014,30.014L31.952,8.562L51.5,17.609L63.904,0L76.309,17.609L95.857,8.562L97.795,30.014L119.247,31.952L110.199,51.5L127.809,63.904L110.199,76.309L119.247,95.857L97.795,97.795L95.857,119.247L76.309,110.199L63.904,127.809L51.5,110.199L31.952,119.247L30.014,97.795L8.562,95.857L17.609,76.309Z" />
      </svg>
```

That's what I'm after no matter the shapes fill opacity.

Any thoughts as to how I can get a solid color (like black) and alpha = 100% of the `SourceGraphic`, and then be able to modify the color and it's opacity to any color/opacity I like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not setting the alpha to 100% in your original feColorMatrix - you're multiplying the alpha by 1. If you want to set alpha to 100% - you should set the fifth column to 1 (not the fourth column).

Now the problem with that is that it sets all the background to 100% opacity as well so you get the rest of the graphic colored solid black.

But - we have a hack to get around this. Instead of using SourceAlpha - use SourceGraphic, and use the first three columns of the alpha row to boost the alpha of just the colored pixels to 100%. The result is a little crispy (because we nuke anti-aliasing) - but it does get you what you want and works for every color - including rgb(1,1,1).

If you know your colors are not going to be that close to black then, you can dial down those 255's to something more reasonable (like 5 or 10) & retain at least some of the anti-aliasing.

```html
      <svg x="10" y="10" overflow="visible" stroke="#0000FF" stroke-miterlimit="8" stroke-width="4" style="background:grey" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
        <defs>
        <filter id="offsetColoredShape" height="500%" width="500%" x="-275%" y="-275%">
         <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" values="
                                        0 0 0 0 1 
                                        0 0 0 0 0.439
                                        0 0 0 0 0 
                                        255 255 255 1 0"
                                       result="changeToOrangeFill"/>


     <feOffset dx="80"/>
     </filter>               
  </defs>
<use xlink:href="#star" filter="url(#offsetColoredShape)" />
        <path id="star" fill="rgb(255,112,0)" fill-opacity="0.5" d="M0,63.904L17.609,51.5L8.562,31.952L30.014,30.014L31.952,8.562L51.5,17.609L63.904,0L76.309,17.609L95.857,8.562L97.795,30.014L119.247,31.952L110.199,51.5L127.809,63.904L110.199,76.309L119.247,95.857L97.795,97.795L95.857,119.247L76.309,110.199L63.904,127.809L51.5,110.199L31.952,119.247L30.014,97.795L8.562,95.857L17.609,76.309Z" />
      </svg>
```

Comment: That is perfect, exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, if I add `color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"` to the filter, it's the exact color needed, eg rgb=(255,112,0). Again, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the `#star` path in the `<defs>` with no fill or stroke and you can use it the first time with the `fill-opacity="0.5"`and the blue stroke and the second time with the filter, if this is what you need.

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-10 -10 360 150" class="slide" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" fill-rule="evenodd">
     

        <defs>
          <path id="star" stroke-miterlimit="8" d="M0,63.904L17.609,51.5L8.562,31.952L30.014,30.014L31.952,8.562L51.5,17.609L63.904,0L76.309,17.609L95.857,8.562L97.795,30.014L119.247,31.952L110.199,51.5L127.809,63.904L110.199,76.309L119.247,95.857L97.795,97.795L95.857,119.247L76.309,110.199L63.904,127.809L51.5,110.199L31.952,119.247L30.014,97.795L8.562,95.857L17.609,76.309Z" />
        <filter id="offsetColoredShape" height="500%" width="500%" x="-275%" y="-275%">
         <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="
                                        0 0 0 0 1 
                                        0 0 0 0 0.439
                                        0 0 0 0 0 
                                        0 0 0 1 0"
                                       result="changeToOrangeFill"/>

     <feComponentTransfer result="changedAgain">
            <feFuncR type="linear" slope="1" />
            <feFuncG type="linear" slope="0.439" />
            <feFuncB type="linear" slope="0" />
            <feFuncA type="linear" slope="1" />
</feComponentTransfer>

     <feOffset dx="120"/>
     </filter>               
  </defs>
<use xlink:href="#star" filter="url(#offsetColoredShape)" />
<use xlink:href="#star" fill="rgb(255,112,0)" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke="#0000FF"  stroke-width="4" />
      </svg>
```

#### UPDATE

The OP is commenting:

> I'm wondering why, despite discarding all color values and setting alpha to 100% in feColorMatrix the alpha values are retained.

It's because the used element (i.e the `#star`) has `fill-opacity="0.5"`. You need to use an element without the `fill-opacity` attribute.

In this simple example you can see that I can not modify the `fill` of the `<use>` since the used element has a fill. However I can add a stroke since the `<use>` element has no stroke:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50">
    <circle  id="c" fill="deepPink"  stroke-width="5" cx="20" cy="25" r="10"></circle>
  <use xlink:href="#c" x="50" fill="gold" stroke="skyBlue" />
</svg>
```

The OP is also commenting that the previous solution

> doesn't work as the shapes are generated and the filters are simply inserted after the fact.

In the next demo I'm generating the `#star`. Next I'm generating the filtered `<use>` element and it works

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
const SVG_XLINK = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
const svg = document.querySelector("svg")
let d = "M0,63.904 L17.609,51.5L8.562,31.952L30.014,30.014L31.952,8.562L51.5,17.609L63.904,0L76.309,17.609L95.857,8.562L97.795,30.014L119.247,31.952L110.199,51.5L127.809,63.904L110.199,76.309L119.247,95.857L97.795,97.795L95.857,119.247L76.309,110.199L63.904,127.809L51.5,110.199L31.952,119.247L30.014,97.795L8.562,95.857L17.609,76.309Z"

let star = drawSVGelmt({d:d,id:"star"},"path", theDefs);



let use1 = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'use');
use1.setAttributeNS(SVG_XLINK, 'xlink:href', '#star');
use1.setAttribute('class', 'filtered');

svg.appendChild(use1)


function drawSVGelmt(o,tag, parent) {
  
  let elmt = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, tag);
  for (let name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      elmt.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  parent.appendChild(elmt);
  return elmt;
}
```

```css
.filtered{filter:url(#offsetColoredShape)}
```

```html
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-10 -10 360 150" class="slide" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" fill-rule="evenodd">
     

        <defs id="theDefs">

        <filter id="offsetColoredShape" height="500%" width="500%" x="-275%" y="-275%">
         <feColorMatrix in="SourceAlpha" type="matrix" values="
                                        0 0 0 0 1 
                                        0 0 0 0 0.439
                                        0 0 0 0 0 
                                        0 0 0 1 0"
                                       result="changeToOrangeFill"/>

     <feComponentTransfer result="changedAgain">
            <feFuncR type="linear" slope="1" />
            <feFuncG type="linear" slope="0.439" />
            <feFuncB type="linear" slope="0" />
            <feFuncA type="linear" slope="1" />
</feComponentTransfer>

     <feOffset dx="120"/>
     </filter>               
  </defs>

<use xlink:href="#star" fill="rgb(255,112,0)" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke="#0000FF"  stroke-width="4" />
      </svg>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had thought of this, but for my situation it doesn't work as the shapes are generated and the filters are simply inserted after the fact. I'm wondering why, despite discarding all color values and setting alpha to 100% in `feColorMatrix` the alpha values are retained. Is the filter broken or am I not understanding how it actually works?